# Как посмотреть историю платежей Sberbank API?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как получать историю платежей счёта Сбербанка с помощью Sberbank API или иных API, начиная с установки модуля, заканчивая получением определённой информации из последнего платежа?

Answer (score 0):

то что вы спросили, довольно просто гуглится https://developer.sberbank.ru/doc/v3/sbbol/partners-statement

Comment: а разве там есть примеры для Python SDK?

Comment: А есть новая ссылка на API?
То, что написал автор выше - в данный момент не работает.
502 Bad Gateway